# Passing in "embedding" as a Callable is deprecated

Tags: langchain, py-langchain, pinecone

This piece of code seems to not work. Even though this is the way that Pinecone have stated in their documentation that it should look like.

`vectorstore = Pinecone(index, embeddings.embed_query, text_field)`

The error/warning is

`C:\Users\ndira\casetext-test-server\Lib\site-packages\langchain\vectorstores\pinecone.py:59: UserWarning: Passing in "embedding" as a Callable is deprecated. Please pass in an Embeddings object instead.   warnings.warn(`

I don't know any other way of solving this. Kindly help thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `embeddings.embed_query` with `embeddings` and the warning should clear.
The documentation has not been updated it seems